# Callback request failed due to an internal server error after publishing a website Through IIS

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have implemented  my code and it works fine in visual studio 2015 but when I deploy the web site to the IIS. It Work fine in my local machine.
While opening other system thorugh my ip it does not show any validation message. It shows error message is "Callback request failed due to an internal server error." doesn't view my message.

can any one help me

Comment: My guess is that you neglected to deploy the required DevExpress assemblies with your web application. I'd advise you to review the [Redistribution and Deployment documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument15319) and the 
[Assembly Deployment Tool documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AssemblyDeploymentTool/CustomDocument17237).

Comment: I followed above steps (Redistribution and Deployment documentation and the Assembly Deployment Tool documentation) . But it still remains the same error.

Comment: I think you're going to need to try to get a more helpful error message, perhaps by adding a global exception handler to your Global.asax file. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple mistake go to web Config file

change  to

```
 <customErrors mode="Off" />
```

may be it will work

Comment: Adding to this answer, this won't solve your problem, it will just show the real error instead of the generic one